# Grouping of items based on criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of items:

```
ShelvesToPack = [{'ShelfLength': 2278.0, 'ShelfWidth': 356.0, 'ShelfArea': 759152.0, 'ItemNames': 1},
{'ShelfLength': 1220.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 372100.0, 'ItemNames': 2},
{'ShelfLength': 2310.0, 'ShelfWidth': 762.0, 'ShelfArea': 1760220.0, 'ItemNames': 3},
{'ShelfLength': 610.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 1450435.0, 'ItemNames': 4}]
```

I need the program that tells how many minimum number of groups one can have and how the items are grouped.

I would like to form groups of these items such that sum of shelflength of items <= max length or sum of shelfwidth of items  <= max width and sum of ShelfArea of items <= Max Area. In this case, if we look at the logic we can have all the items packed in minimum 2 groups - item 1 and 3 will form one group and item 2 & 4 will form other group. I would like to have the answer in the format:

```
[[{'ShelfLength': 2278.0, 'ShelfWidth': 356.0, 'ShelfArea': 759152.0, 'ItemNames': 1} ,
 {'ShelfLength': 2310.0, 'ShelfWidth': 762.0, 'ShelfArea': 1760220.0, 'ItemNames': 3}],
[{'ShelfLength': 1220.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 372100.0, 'ItemNames': 2},
 , {'ShelfLength': 610.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 1450435.0, 'ItemNames': 4}]]
```

I have written a code but it does not give the result I wanted.

```
ShelvesToPack_sorted = sorted(ShelvesToPack, key = itemgetter('ShelfWidth'), reverse = True)
AreaOfObject = 2972897.28
current_width = 0
current_length = 0
current_area = 0
ply =[]
plywoods=[]
for item in ShelvesToPack_sorted:
    if (current_width + item['ShelfWidth'] <= 1219.2  or  current_length + item['ShelfLength'] <= 2438.5) and  current_area + item['ShelfArea'] <= AreaOfObject:
        ply.append(item)
        current_width += item['ShelfWidth']
        current_length += item['ShelfLength']
        current_area += item['ShelfArea']
    else:
       plywoods.append(ply)
       if (item['ShelfWidth'] <= 1219.2  or item['ShelfLength'] <= 2438.5) and item['ShelfArea'] <= AreaOfObject:
           ply = [item]
           current_width = item['ShelfWidth']
           current_length = item['ShelfLength']
           current_area = item['ShelfArea']
       else:
           ply = []
           current_width = 0
           current_length = 0
           current_area = 0

if ply:
    plywoods.append(ply)

print(plywoods)
```

I have got the following output which is not quite right and I am unable to do the correct grouping.

```
[[{'ItemNames': 3, 'ShelfWidth': 762.0, 'ShelfLength': 310.0, 'ShelfArea': 1760220.0}],
 [{'ItemNames': 2, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfLength': 1220.0, 'ShelfArea': 372100.0},
  {'ItemNames': 4, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfLength': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 1450435.0}],
 [{'ItemNames': 1, 'ShelfWidth': 356.0, 'ShelfLength': 2278.0, 'ShelfArea': 759152.0}]]
```

Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: well, all items satisfy the condition `(item['ShelfWidth'] <= 1219.2  or item['ShelfLength']  <= 2438.5) and item['ShelfArea'] <= AreaOfObject`

Comment: You need to rethink the logic you're applying. This seems flawed.

Comment: So do you have 2 groups? Ones that satisfy the conditions and ones that do not? Is that it?

Comment: I wrote it in else statement.  Without it the output is as below: [[{'ShelfLength': 2310.0, 'ShelfArea': 1760220.0, 'ShelfWidth': 762.0, 'ItemNames': 3}, {'ShelfLength': 2278.0, 'ShelfArea': 759152.0, 'ShelfWidth': 356.0, 'ItemNames': 1}]]

Comment: Well I need the program that tells how many minimum  number of groups one can have and how the items are grouped. In this case, if we look at the logic we can have all the items packed in  minimum 2 groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
data = [{'ShelfLength': 2278.0, 'ShelfWidth': 356.0, 'ShelfArea': 759152.0, 'ItemNames': 1},
    {'ShelfLength': 1220.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea':   372100.0, 'ItemNames': 2},
    {'ShelfLength': 2310.0, 'ShelfWidth': 762.0, 'ShelfArea': 1760220.0, 'ItemNames': 3},
    {'ShelfLength': 610.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0,   'ShelfArea': 1450435.0, 'ItemNames': 4}]
SL = 'ShelfLength'
SW = 'ShelfWidth'
SA = 'ShelfArea'
IN = 'ItemNames'
max_width = 1219.2
max_len = 2438.5
max_area = 2972897.28

grouped_data = [[], []]
for record in data:
    if (record[SL] <= max_len or record[SW] <= max_width) and record[SA] <= max_area:
        grouped_data[0].append(record)
    else:
        grouped_data[1].append(record)

print(grouped_data)
```

This gives the same result you got, which is correct given that all elements satisfy the condition you mentioned.

Comment: Actually I  need to find what is the minimum number of groups and how the items are grouped together. In the above code we have fixed number of items in grouped data   which works fine in the above data set ( the answer is 2 ) but it may not work for all data sets.

Comment: @user6757642 of course, because the way you described your problem there *are* only two possible groupings. Perhaps you could better describe what is the more general problem you want to solve?

Comment: "I need a program that tells how many minimum number of groups one can have and how the items are grouped. I would like to form groups of these items such that shelflength <= max length or shelfwidth <= max width and ShelfArea <= Max Area."  In the above case we have 2 - which may not be true always.....

Comment: @user6757642 if your condition is for some elements to be lesser/greater than something you indeed have only two possible grouping. Or do you mean that you have a certain number of boundaries and you want to group the items based on those? Could you post an example which would result in three groupings?

Comment: @glsThanks ......."you have a certain number of boundaries and you want to group the items based on those?" -- yes this is what I meant. and the boundaries are:shelflength <= max length or shelfwidth <= max width and ShelfArea <= Max Area.

Comment: @user6757642 that is a single condition, resulting in only two groups. You need more conditions for more groups. You should post an example with more than two groupings to make clear what you mean

Comment: @gls....As of now I do not have a data set. But for example we can  have 5 more items (consider the same dimensions of last item) then we cannot have two groups because the sum of the items in one group will exceed the max width so we have to have another group ( may be two  more groups ) of items. I hope I am able to clear the doubt. The two groups I mentioned was just for an example for the above data set.

Comment: @user6757642 what does the sum have to do with the problem? you haven't mentioned any sum in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that appears to work correctly. Since the order of shelves in a combination doesn't matter, it simply does things using a brute-force approach that checks every possible combination of the shelves. Because there may be a very large number of them to process, it's important to write code which is fairly efficient. There are probably more optimal algorithms that would accomplishing this faster—in what is essentially a searching or path-finding problem.

With that in mind and to make accessing the fields in each shelf dictionary easier, it first converts them all into an equivalent list of `namedtuple` instances which are used by the code from that point on. (If you really need them in dictionary form, it would be simple to keep a copy of it around or recreate it when necessary.)

Once the conversion is done, it then checks all combinations of shelf items in the range from 1 to all of them. It stores these it finds in a list named `groups`. `group[N]` will contain a sublist of the combinations of `N` items that met the criteria. (And the length of that sublist is the number of combinations of that number of shelves found, of course).

So, for example, in the output far below, it shows that there were 4 groups of 2 items that meet the criteria. (It doesn't print each combination of them, however.)

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter

shelves_to_pack = [
    {'ShelfLength': 2278.0, 'ShelfWidth': 356.0, 'ShelfArea': 759152.0, 'ItemNames': 1},
    {'ShelfLength': 1220.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 372100.0, 'ItemNames': 2},
    {'ShelfLength': 2310.0, 'ShelfWidth': 762.0, 'ShelfArea': 1760220.0, 'ItemNames': 3},
    {'ShelfLength': 610.0, 'ShelfWidth': 610.0, 'ShelfArea': 1450435.0, 'ItemNames': 4}]

# convert dict list into a namedtuple list to simplify field access
Shelf = namedtuple('Shelf',
                   'length width area item_names')
shelves = [Shelf(length=shelf['ShelfLength'], width=shelf['ShelfWidth'],
                 area=shelf['ShelfArea'], item_names=shelf['ItemNames'])
            for shelf in shelves_to_pack]

MAX_WIDTH, MAX_LENGTH = 1219.2, 2438.5
MAX_AREA = 2972897.28

def meets_criteria(shelf_combo):
    """ Determine if shelf combination meets criteria. """
    return (sum(shelf.area for shelf in shelf_combo) <= MAX_AREA
            and (sum(shelf.length for shelf in shelf_combo) <= MAX_LENGTH
                 or sum(shelf.width for shelf in shelf_combo) <= MAX_WIDTH))

groups = [[]]  # first group representing zero shelf items is always empty
for num_shelves in range(1, len(shelves)+1):
    groups.append([combo for combo in combinations(shelves, num_shelves)
                      if meets_criteria(combo)])
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    print('groups of {} items: size {}'.format(i, len(group)))
```

This is the output generated from the code and input data above:

```
groups of 0 items: size 0
groups of 1 items: size 4
groups of 2 items: size 4
groups of 3 items: size 0
groups of 4 items: size 0
```